# PHP looping custom fields with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

So I have this code I want to repeat. Uses wordpress acf to generate the image:

```
`<div class="row">
    <?php if( get_field('image_1') ): ?>
        <img class="this-image" src="<?php the_field('image_1'); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>`
```

I'm just wondering how I can loop this in with which I would also need to increment the numbers (ie. image_1, image_2, image_3).

I'm having trouble figuring out the logic of PHP, if there already is a similar post, a kind link would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use a `For Loop` or `While Loop` to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code - it is using for loop to iterate through all images from image_1 to image_X (where X can be defined by you). similar code can be modified by add an array to store all the image names, just in case if there is no patterns for the image names.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $numImages = 10; #Define how many images you have
     for ($i=1; $i<= $numImages; $i++){ #starting from image_1 ?>
    <?php if( get_field('image_' . $i)): ?>
          <img class="this-image" src="<?php the_field('image_' . $i); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Though I'm having trouble understanding how the curly braces work in this case?

Does it simply help separate the for loop and if statements?

Comment: It's just simple open and close braces for the for loop syntax, it's the same as 

`foreach ($array as $item):`
`endforeach;`

Comment: Ah, I understand. How about in the case I want to repeat the row twice, while maintaining the same for loop within?

Comment: so you put the loop into a function say `foo()`
and then every time you need to use the loop just call it. for example
`<div class="row">  <!--row 1 -->
      foo();
</div>`

`<div class="row">  <!--row 2 -->
      foo();
</div>`

Comment: And that would still increment in order? It won't restart every time the function is called?

Comment: you can probably give the function parameters, for example `foo($startingNum, $numOfImageForTheRow)`, then you call the function `foo(10,5)` so it will generate the images from image_10 to image_15.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
`<div class="row">
    <?php 
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    if( get_field('image_'.i) ): ?>
        <img class="this-image" src="<?php the_field('image_'.i); ?>" />
    <?php endif; } ?>
</div>`
```